# How do I move custom button to modal footer

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, modal

I have a lightning action component that fires from a record page. Opens a modal for creation of a related object. In this draft I can get the button to appear in the modal content but I can't figure out how to move it to the parent container. I've tried many different things and it never shows in the parent at all, let alone in the bottom by the cancel button where I would like it. Please help

[image]

Parent action component. Button does not show anywhere

```
<aura:component implements="force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickAction,lightning:actionOverride" access="global">

  <div class="slds-modal">
    <div class="slds-modal__container">
      <div class="slds-modal__content myDiv">
        <c:abNewAgreementBillable/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer slds-modal__footer">
    <lightning:button label="Submit" onclick="{!c.handleSubmit}"/>
  </div>
</aura:component>
```

Child component. This button shows but not in the wrapper where I would like it

```
<aura:component access="global">
  <aura:attribute name="bType" type="String" default="Standard"/>
  <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
  <lightning:notificationsLibrary aura:id="notifLib" />

  <div class="div">
    <div>
      <lightning:select name="bType" label="&nbsp;Billable Type" value="{!v.bType}" >
        <option value="Standard">Standard</option>
        <option value="Minimum">Minimum</option>
        <option value="Tiered">Tiered</option>
      </lightning:select>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.bType=='Standard'}">
      Show input for a Standard billable item
    </aura:if>
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.bType=='Minimum'}">
      Show input for a billable item with a minimum amount billed
    </aura:if>
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.bType=='Tiered'}">
      Show input options for Tiered billing with possible minimum amount
    </aura:if>
    <br/>&nbsp;
    
  </div>

  <div class="modal-footer slds-modal__footer">
    <lightning:button label="Submit" onclick="{!c.handleSubmit}"/>
  </div>
</aura:component>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The header and footer comes up by default when you use [force:lightningQuickAction](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:lightningQuickAction/documentation). This interface display in a panel with standard action controls, such as a Cancel button. These components can display and implement their own controls in the body of the panel, but can’t affect the standard controls.

So, in order to fix your issue, You need to switch to [force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader/documentation). This interface display in a panel without additional controls. The component should provide a complete user interface for the action.

Additionally, you can add Header and footer in the parent markup to bring your submit in the footer.

Your component will look like this with **force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader**

[image: taken from https://technogeeksfdc.com/2019/01/17/custom-header-and-footer-in-lightning-quick-action/]